# Is it wrong to use "The Albatross is now on the sky"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, in-on

Is it wrong to use "The Albatross is now **on** the sky"?

Is it like we should always say "The Albatross is now **in** the sky"?

I would like to get an explanation for this. Thanks.

Comment: Please also visit http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: An albatross is in the _air_. The sun and moon are in the _sky_.

Comment: Let's see.  Capital letter in Albatross?  Maybe the Albatross is the name of a helicopter, and the landing pad on the roof of the skyscraper is called "the sky".  Then I can say *The Albatross is on the sky."  But it is far-fetched.

Comment: @GEdgar I was going to try and work that angle into my answer, but decided not to, I had imagined that "the Albatross" was the internal code name of a television documentary project and "the sky" was the internal code name of a particular subject, and that the statement was being used by some kind of executive or other decision maker to communicate that the subject of the planned television program had changed

Comment: @GEdgar I can also imagine a statement such as "the albatross is now on the sky" would fit quite nicely into an episode of Allo Allo as said by the character Michelle Dubois who was known for saying ["Listen very carefully; I shall say this only once."](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086659/quotes?item=qt0421994) followed by statements that would typically resemble the structure of "The Albatross is now on the sky"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement is not correct

> The Albatross is now on the sky

It is not possible to put an albatross **onto** the sky, because of what the sky is, it is not possible to put anything **on** the sky

It should be

> The Albatross is now in the sky

But, using **on** in the following statement would be fine

> The Albatross is now on the water

Because it is possible to put things **onto** water, you can also put things **into** water.

Perhaps these definitions of [on](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on#on_28), [in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in#in_17) and [sky](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sky) will help

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have an answer that explains the difference between the prepositions on and in, but looking at the entirety of the thought (a large bird going from land to air), both of your options seem awkward. Some more natural sounding alternatives are:

- The Albatross has now taken flight.
- The Albatross is now airborne.
- The Albatross is now aloft.